# Integration with Facebook Graph Api - update mechanism without Real-Time Updates

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

- I'm working on a project which uses Facebook Graph Api to download information about users of our application and their Facebook friends. There is a need to update this data, but as I understand Real-Time Update is not an option. For example I would like to have update of profile feed of friends of our app user, and I don't see a way to do this with Real-Time Update.
- Could someone give me some advice on this update mechanism? I need to update app users, their friend connections and profile feeds of users and their friends. I understand I'll have to poll Facebook servers to retrieve this data. What I'm trying to find out is some good practices when doing these things. Update frequency? Way to recognize that data has changed? If anyone has experience with this kind of things every advice would mean a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: organize your questions (use bullets)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the since= query string parameter of the Graph API call. Here's some pseudocode to help you along

```
var usersLastPostDate = GetLastPostDateFromDataStore(userId);
if(usersLastPostDate not populated) {
   streamItems = GraphApiGet(userId, "me/feed")
   lastStreamItemDate = GetNewestStreamItemDate(streamItems)
   StoreLastPostDateIntoDataStore(userId, lastStreamItemDate )
}
else {
   streamItems = GraphApiGet(userId, "me/feed?since=" + usersLastPostDate )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, i will try the since parameter

Comment: If you feel this answered your question, please be sure to accept this answer so 

the question doesn't show up on the unanswered list.  See: 

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Ok, I'll do that as soon as I have some feedback about solutions

Comment: Since would be very useful if I could use it on post's updated_time instead of created_time because I want to pick up new likes and comments on existing posts...I didn't find a way to do use updated_time at all in my request (even with the FQL).

Comment: That's a different question.  Please start a new question on StackOverflow for that.

Answer (score 0):

Not massively useful for your use case (as you're wanting to get data which changes frequently), but worth pointing out that the Graph API now supports ETags - https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/627/.

ETags will tell you if the data has changed since the last time you requested it. This won't stop you from hitting Facebooks API throttling limits, but is a quick and easy way to tell if the data has changed since you last asked for it.

There is no one answer to your question, as it depends on what your application is doing. How often do you need to get the updated information? If your data is stale for 5 minutes, is that really a problem? Can you grab the data from Facebook lazily, when some user action requires that you have it?

If you do need to do a lot of polling try and use non-blocking IO, especially if you're expecting to have a lot of open HTTP requests to Facebook whilst you're polling. Build a reliable queueing mechanism and HTTP poker to ensure requests are being made as expected. Without any idea of what technology stack you're using it's hard to be more specific than that.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for that detailed reply. I will try to use ETags for data that doesn’t change frequently. Data could be stale for some time, I'll try to find some trade-off between outdated information and frequent polling. Update isn't triggered by user action, it's going to be a separate server also. I'm using RestFb rest api client for retrieving data from FB.

Answer (score 0):

What about this: [Open Graph Subscription system](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/subscription/) ?

Comment: I think that is the Real-Time update. I mentioned above that I don't think it meets my requirements. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @njosa, you are correct.  The link they provided is for Real-Time updates.

Comment: I think you can. I just did this for a fb application and it works as stated. After ~30sec of profile modification (I subscribed to friend list changes) I get a callback from fb telling me that I have to update my cache for that user friend list.